# How to view unresponsive pages?

Tags: windows, google-chrome, microsoft-edge, webpage

I am currently trying to view [this](https://terrytao.wordpress.com/books/analysis-i/) webpage of Terence Tao. I have tried Microsoft Edge, and Google Chrome, both at their latest update versions. I've trying to view them for days now (on my laptop). But it always snaps, showing an unresponsive page. Waiting doesn't fix it.

Comment: Are you sure you don't have anything blocking access to the site? It comes right up for me in Chrome 89 and Edge 90.

Comment: Have you tried typing the url into google.com and selecting cached? or `wget` it and read it offline?

Comment: No repro on Windows 7 Home Premium 64 bit, Firefox 88.0

Comment: The entirely of it is around 7.8MB ( about 20MB on disk apparently).   https://i.imgur.com/RheIsN1.png  You need a good internet connection and working computer, and to wait a minute. Try from some different laptops, and at some different libraries or cafes.

Comment: if it's urgent you can extract this zip and open the html in chrome  and if it's urgrent, you can extract this zip file and open it in chrome.. that's the webpage saved from chrome   https://drive.google.com/file/d/1NMbjGl6xsPwCGSjoig_tMhy1k2_NWb2z/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

This website is extremely slow, but works for me. Just wait for it to download.

If it's still not working, use one of its copies on the
[Wayback Machine](https://web.archive.org/web/20210601000000*/https://terrytao.wordpress.com/books/analysis-i/),
but just be warned that this might be even slower.